# Cambiar la extension /wp-admin por una especifica

Tags: wordpress, backend

pues mi pregunta es si puedo cambiar la url de wordpress /wp-admin por una que por ejemplo se llame /web-secreta, a poder ser sin plugins, es que he encontrado algunas soluciones pero no las llego a pillar del todo.

Un saludo a tod@s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar la funión [wp_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) añadiendo este trocito de código en el fichero [functions.php](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/)

```
  add_action('init','custom_login');

  function custom_login(){
    global $pagenow;
    if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
    wp_redirect('http://midominio.com/web-secreta');
    exit();
    } 
  }
```

Esto inicializa la función `custom-login` que detecta si se está accediendo a la página de login y redirige a la página deseada.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto

**Nota:** Debes estar logueado en wordpress primero.

1- Ir a **wp-config.php** y agregar lo siguiente:

```
define('WP_ADMIN_DIR', 'backend');
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', SITECOOKIEPATH . WP_ADMIN_DIR);
```

2- Añadir este codigo en el function.php de tu tema.

```
add_filter('site_url',  'wpadmin_filter', 10, 3);

function wpadmin_filter( $url, $path, $orig_scheme ) {
$request_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$check_wp_admin = stristr($request_url, 'wp-admin');
if($check_wp_admin and !is_user_logged_in()){
    wp_redirect( home_url( '404' ), 302 );
    exit();
}
/**Esto permite mantener la carpeta wp-admin**/
$old  = array( "/(wp-admin)/");
$admin_dir = WP_ADMIN_DIR;
$new  = array($admin_dir);
return preg_replace( $old, $new, $url, 1);
}

add_rewrite_rule( '^' . 'backend/(.*)','wp-admin/$1?%{QUERY_STRING}' ); 
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

3- Reemplaza la palabrá "**backend**", por la que quieras. y accedes como **misitio.com/backend/** (con la barra al final /)

4- Ve a Ajustes -> Enlaces permanente y dar a guardar cambios.

Eso es todo.
Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090866/change-wordpress-admin-url